# create own mail id with mydomain.in

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server

I want to create my own mail ID like `myname@mydomain.in` instead of paying extra to google for extra mail ids as I have already `myname@mycompany.in`.

Things I have are `mydomain.in`(I paid for this domain name and this domain.in is pointing to our staging server say IP xx.xx.xx.xx), system with Ubuntu server.

I tried setup Postfix,  when install Postfix server

```
Internet site:  mydomain.in.
Root and postmaster mail recipient: root
mydestinations:  mydomain.in, localhost.example.com, localhost
```

rest all default.

Now I am able to send mail from postfix mail server by command `$ sendmail myname@gmail.com 'message'`. I checked `myname@gmail.com` I got mail from `root@mydomain.in`. I try reply to `root@mydomain.in` from `myname@gmail.com` but there is no mail received under root. This is the file in ubuntu server `/var/mail/root` where mails received, it is empty.

I want if someone send mail to `root@mydomain.in` should be saved in ubuntu server.

Please let me know if you don't understand my question.

Answer (score 3):

This could be many things

- Did you set up [MX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) records in the [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) that resolve to your new mail server ?
- Do you have a border device that needs to know that it should forward connections on [port 25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) to your staging sever?
- Do you have a firewall that needs to be configured to allow connections to port 25 on your staging server ?

---

Have you had any bounce messages and have you looked carefully at the information they contain to help you diagnose the problem ?

Comment: ans for question1: there is no MX in mydomain.in. I did `dig mx mydomain.in`. where should I set MX whether in staging server or in bigrock.in where we bought this name from.

Comment: ans for question3: result of `telnet mydomain.in 25` gives `Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...` I guess port 25 in staging server is blocked by firewall. I need to contact my admin to allow port 25.

Comment: ans for question2: I don't have any device to forward connections. Where should I have that device or can't I forward connection to ubuntu server. I have no idea about this can you guide me to make it work around.

Comment: I don't have any bounce message back or failure notice to my gmail account.

Comment: result of `dig mx mydomain.in` is `;;QUESTION SECTION: mydomain.in IN MX ;;AUTHORITY SECTION: mydomain.in 7200 IN SOA dns1.bigrock.in. 201...3  7200 7200`

Comment: @lain what would be other possible problems.

Comment: @niren: There are several issues you need to resolve before moving on and I'm sure that one of them will fix your problem. In the event that a domain doesn't have MX records, then the sender will fall back to the relevant A record, in your case mydomain.in so if you have a host with an A record that points to mydomain.in that is where mail will likely be delivered. To be honest I thik you're way out of your depth ...

Answer (score 1):

Mail should not be received by root. You need to specify another user to receive root's mail.

`/etc/aliases` should look something like this:

```
# /etc/aliases
mailer-daemon: postmaster
postmaster: root
nobody: root
hostmaster: root
usenet: root
news: root
webmaster: root
www: root
ftp: root
abuse: root
noc: root
security: root
root: niren
```

Besides, in order to see why your e-mail does not arrive, you should look at logs. We cannot help further without that.